# load a large (200 GB) Hbase table into a RDD without going through Hbase scans

Tags: hbase

I would like to load a large (200 GB) Hbase table into a RDD without going through Hbase scans i.e. read HFiles directly into an RDD.

It will be great if you can share any example/sample code (or links to web pages with example) that shows use of HFileInputformat as ones I found were pointing to source code of HFileInputformat.

Not sure if dangers mentioned here in 2012/2013 still applies - http://qnalist.com/questions/155178/hfileinputformat-for-mapreduce

Answer (score 0):

I found this for .94. https://gist.github.com/ashwanthkumar/5133733

But dangers still exist. If a compaction or region split occurs at the same time, it will effects your result.

Comment: Thanks ozhang for the pointer. As I had mentioned the link only shows the source code for the HFileInputFormat class. I am looking for an example where HFileInputformat is used.

 I am also curious to know how (if?) this will work with an HBase table with multiple column families as each column family will have its own HFile and the "splits" provided by MR framework is by region.

Also not sure what will be the Key and value returned by HFileInputformat eg if within a column family HFile we have multiple columns stored as KV pairs.